# Conditionally replacing cell values with value in another column in R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I am dealing with a large crash dataset in R where each row represents a unique automobile crash (ID). With each crash, there is an associated total number of fatalities. I also have columns representing the combinations of cars that were in the crash (car/car, bus/car, truck/car). Each crash can only have one combination of vehicles coded as 1.

This is a mini-version of what my dataset looks like:

```
ID fatalities car/car bus/car truck/car
1     2        0        1       0
2     3        1        0       0
3     1        0        1       0
```

I would like to replace the 1/0 coding for vehicles in the crash with the total number of fatalities. I eventually would like to sum the number of fatalities by crash type.

Here is what I want my dataset to look like:

```
ID fatalities car/car bus/car truck/car
1     2        0        2       0
2     3        3        0       0
3     1        0        1       0
```

I could use ifelse statements, but this would be super tedious in my real dataset with 42 different possible parties involved in a crash instead of 3. I think it would be very easy to use colsum to get the totals for car/car, bus/car, and truck/car once they are filled in with the appropriate totals.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have more columns, just use `colnames(df)` to get column names and provide the column names to `.vars` argument.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
    ~crash_Id, ~fatalities, ~`car/car`,~`bus/car`,~`truck/car`,
    1,2,0,1,0,
    2,3,1,0,0,
    3,1,0,1,0
)


out <- mutate_at(.tbl = df,
          .vars = c("car/car","bus/car","truck/car"),
          .funs = ~ . * fatalities)
```

```
> out 
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  crash_Id fatalities `car/car` `bus/car` `truck/car`
     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1        1          2         0         2           0
2        2          3         3         0           0
3        3          1         0         1           0
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! The code works perfectly. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way in base R -

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) x * df$fatalities)
result <- rbind(df, TOTAL = colSums(df))

        fatalities car.car bus.car truck.car
crash 1          2       0       2         0
crash 2          3       3       0         0
crash 3          1       0       1         0
TOTAL            6       3       3         0
```

**Note:** I wouldn't recommend structuring your data like this for analysis. It is OK if you are doing this to export the result to a file or something.

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(fatalities = c(2L, 3L, 1L), car.car = c(0L, 1L, 
0L), bus.car = c(1L, 0L, 1L), truck.car = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("fatalities", 
"car.car", "bus.car", "truck.car"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("crash 1", 
"crash 2", "crash 3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Yeah, this structure is not ideal for analysis. Like you mentioned, this is more of a last step for exporting.